# codenameone UWP issue

Tags: uwp, codenameone

I display the help in my app using the WebBroser:

```
WebBrowser html = new WebBrowser();
html.setURL("jar:///help.html");
```

When I run the app in Windows 10 I get the following error:

> cli.System.ArgumentException: the given System.Uri cannot be converted into a Windows.Foundation.Uri

Answer (score 0):

That looks like an issue in the UWP port which is still pretty new and under active development. A [brief search](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20uwp) shows that it isn't reported yet so I suggest reporting it to get it fixed for the 3.5 release.